# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, badpaddingexception

I'm creating an AES key using the `KeyGenerator` class. Then I exposed a web service to do encryption and decryption using this AES key and return the cipher text/plain text in web service response.

Encryption is working perfectly fine but when I call the web service (from [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/)) for decryption, I'm getting `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded` exception intermittently.

I'm using hexadecimal (using the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` class) encoding/decoding to convert bytes in to `String` and vice versa.

I created a standalone class to test this code and working without any issues.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please show the relevant code for your issue, without it we can't give you much.

Comment: BadPaddingException questions here fall into one or more of the following categories: 1) using different keys or IVs for encryption and decryption 2) using lossy encoding for passing encrypted data (think of `String.getBytes()`, especially without specifying encoding) 3) using `InputStream`  on decrypting side and ignoring the return value of `read()` method. Which category is this question, I wonder.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I would bet on stream handling... But the user does not seem to respond anymore.